# AngularJS + Firebase. After logout old user data still exists. Creating new account and old user data gets replaced on firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

So I am following thinksters fantasy football app tutorial but whenever I logout and try creating a new account. The new account gets created and replaces all the information about the old user on firebase with the new user info.

I'm guessing this is a scope issue where it is not getting cleared on logout?

```
'use strict';

/* Services */

angular.module('fantasyApp.services.login', ['fantasyApp.services.profileCreator'])
  .factory('loginService', ['angularFireAuth', 'profileCreator', '$location', '$rootScope',
  function(angularFireAuth, profileCreator, $location, $rootScope) {
  return {
    login: function(email, pass, redirect, callback) {
      var p = angularFireAuth.login('password', {
        email: email,
        password: pass,
        rememberMe: true
      });
      p.then(function(user) {
        if( redirect ) {
          $location.path(redirect);
        }
        callback && callback(null, user);
      }, callback);
    },
    logout: function(redirectPath) {
      angularFireAuth.logout();
      if(redirectPath) {
        $location.path(redirectPath);
        $scope.destroy()
      }
    },
    createAccount: function(name, email, mobile, pass, callback) {
      angularFireAuth._authClient.createUser(email, pass, function(err, user) {
        if(callback) {
          callback(err, user);
          $rootScope.$apply();
        }
      });
    },
    createProfile: profileCreator
  }
}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue relates to this bit of code in the file app/js/controllers/headercontroller.js.

```
$scope.$on('angularFireAuth:login', function() { 
    angularFire(new Firebase(FBURL+'/users/'+$scope.auth.id), $scope, 'user'); 
});
```

What happens here is that every time `angularFireAuth:login` get’s $broadcast‘d, we’re hooking up `$scope.user` to a Firebase ref located at `FBURL+'/users/'+$scope.auth.id`. Now, the issue is that if you log out, then log back in, `angularFireAuth:login` gets $broadcast‘d twice. This wouldn’t be an issue except for the fact that we’re spinning up an angularFire in the callback. The result of this is that we now have two `angularFire`s tied to `$scope.user`. This means, that if `$scope.user` gets changed, we’ll write to two separate Firebase ref’s.

If we attach an `angularFire` to `$scope.user` and, for example `$scope.user` gets set to `{name: "Tyler"}`, then when we log out and log back in, the current value of `$scope.user` gets written to the new `angularFire`, which is tied to a different user's path. This results in this weird account overwriting behavior.

Anyway, the solution is to use the `disassociate()` method passed when `angularFire`’s promise is resolved.

For example, try this.

```
$scope.$on('angularFireAuth:login', function() { 
  if ($scope.disassociateUserData) { 
      $scope.disassociateUserData();
  } 
  angularFire(new Firebase(FBURL+'/users/'+$scope.auth.id), $scope, 'user').then(function (disassociate) { 
      $scope.disassociateUserData = disassociate; 
  }; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey this guys git project doesn't have the same issues we are having, so I am going to follow his code as an example and try to figure out what we are doing wrong.

http://github.com/mattmalenczak/angularfire-login-boilerplate

Update: FOUND IT!

https://github.com/mattmalenczak/angularfire-login-boilerplate/blob/master/js/controllers.js

```
disassociate();
```

It is in the function on line 63, but the function is called on logout line 31!