# JSON Data structure resulting in the least passed data from database

Tags: json, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to understand how I can structure a particular set of data using a JSON object.

Suppose I have a bunch of users and I am storing in my database like so (I'm using firebase):

```
 {
     0--{name:"Dog", details:{somestuffhere}}
     |
     1--{name:"Cat", details:{somestuffhere}}
     |
     2--{name:"Cow", details:{somestuffhere}}
    ...
 }
```

using firebase I can look at JUST the name entry for Dog using
/0/name

The way I understand it, when I make a call to firebase (I'm using angularjs) it'll transfer the entire JSON object across. This works great for smaller datasets, but suppose the dataset increases to even 5MB. The initial load is super slow (in my mind), but then things might not be too bad (although you're just hanging onto a large quantity of data to play with).

I'm trying to think of a way to structure my data so if I wanted to get a list of names ONLY then I pull down the details depending on the name (if the user clicks for example).

Ideally,  I would call /name and it would return all the names ONLY (not the remaining data that's associated).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT:
I used Dog Cat Cow as examples, in reality they are people, and the app can add a name and details (on other pages). I would like to see a list of names first, then click on them as a link, if one exists, if the name doesn't exist, I'll create it, then allow addition of "details". I hope that helps more. (I'm assuming the database will always grow, which is why I said 5MB, in reality it could grow to much more but I don't know, it depends on the usage)

Comment: pretty difficult for anyone here to digest `Dog/Cat/Cow` and `somestuffhere` and turn that into advice on how to structure delivery of 5mb of data for an app they know nothing about

Comment: What you want, of course, is a real database.

Comment: Have to actually agree if you are expecting the DB to grow to somewhere in the MB range and expect your users to be potentially impatient or not willing to wait for a data sync for the convenience of then having all the data and being able to disconnect from the network, then you should just be using a regular database and transfer the data you need.

Comment: I haven't used firebase yet but based on doing a bit of quick research it seems that it relies on syncing the data between clients so I imagine this means the first time it's loaded into the device it's cached somehow and then changes are probably the the diffs.

Comment: @Hot Licks - what's wrong with fake databases? Or did you mean a relational database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The Data Structure

When building with Firebase, denormalizing your data is key. In your scenario I would suggest maintaining a secondary index which only contained the names of your animals with the unique key for loading the details. For example:

```
{
 "names": 
    {
      "Dog": 0,
      "Cat": 1,
      "Cow": 2
    },
 "animals": 
    {
       0: {name:"Dog", details:{somestuffhere}},
       1: {name:"Cat", details:{somestuffhere}},
       2: {name:"Cow", details:{somestuffhere}}
    }
}
```

Now you can use a normal Firebase reference to load all the children of `/names` and you can then decide which details you want to load.

When you add a new animal, just make sure to add a corresponding `/names` entry too.

## Using this Structure with AngularJS

You're correct that AngularFire will load all the data of a given path, however we can limit this using our new data structure. Instead of using a single, generic AngularFire which loads all our data, we can use multiple AngularFires and be more selective.

This first AngularFire loads our list of names.

```
// Load the list of names to $scope.names
angularFire(new Firebase("http://[Your Firebase].firebaseio.com/names"), $scope, "names"));
```

Then once a user selects an animal, a new AngularFire for the path `/names/{Animal}` is used to dynamically load the details of that animal. In this example, it is assumed the unique key for the animal is stored in the `animalKey` variable

```
// Load the specific animal details to $scope.animal
angularFire(new Firebase("http://[Your Firebase].firebaseio.com/animals/").child(animalKey), $scope, "animal"));
```

Now the data for our animal is exposed on `$scope.animal` and we haven't loaded all the unneeded data about the other animals.

## Safely adding new animals

*Addressing a comment on this answer*

As general advice, never use incremented integers as keys in Firebase. Due to the realtime nature of Firebase the likelyhood that two users would add a new item with the same incremented integer key (in this case, `3`), at the same time is very high, which would result in the overwriting of one of their entries. Use Firebase's [`.push()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/push.html) instead.

In your scenario, what you would do is step around AngularFire and use `.push` on a Firebase ref. Try this:

```
var newAnimalRef = (new Firebase('http://[Your Firebase].firebaseio.com'))
    .child('animals')
    .push({name: 'Fish', details: ""});
```

It will create a new child of `/animals` with a key like `-fj213jjkaisdja`. Then we can use `.once` to add the new item to the `/names` index:

```
newAnimalRef.once('value', function (snapshot) { 
    (new Firebase('http://[Your Firebase].firebaseio.com'))
        .child('names')
        .child(snapshot.val().name)
        .set(snapshot.name()) 
});
```

Then boom, we have added a child in a clean, safe way.

## Closing Notes

1. Here is a [link to an official blog post](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html) about denormalizing data and it is a generally good resource if you're coming from working with relational databases.
2. Be careful when potentially creating multiple AngularFires associated to the same field on `$scope`. If you're not careful you can end up with changes to a single field being written to multiple paths in Firebase. To prevent this, either only tie AngularFire to an `$scope` which will be torn down regularly (i.e. a controller specific to the module displaying the animal data) or make use of the disassociate method passed to the resolved promise from AngularFire as I do in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20344334/1570248).

Comment: in response to #3, how would I map animal name to a number as in the example provided, while maintaining the realtime nature? Great response, and while I stewed it over in my mind all night, I came to a similar conclusion.

Comment: Updated my answer with a better explanation.