# Firebase Reference not returned after add

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I do something like this:

```
 var temp = $scope.names.$add({"firstname" : $scope.firstname, "lastname" : $scope.lastname, "school" : $scope.selectedSchool});
```

I get a returned object, but when I try

```
$log.log(temp.toString());
```

I get just the object, whereas the documentation for firebase says I should see the path to the string of my new firebase URL. I also tried

```
$log.log(temp.name());
```

And same result, is this related to the implementation of those "functions" in angularfire, or to actual firebase itself?

I'm trying to syncronize adding "names" to a names portion of my json object, and then following it up with creating a section in my json object where I can get more details of the individual and so I want to match up the key's

kinda like this [JSON Data structure resulting in the least passed data from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485194/json-data-structure-resulting-in-the-least-passed-data-from-database)

I don't see how to get the above to work, and I saw (at one point, can't find the link now), that firebase was recommending using transaction not the "once" operation, so I was hoping I would get the individuals key, then pass that into creating a new firebase "subobject?" that matched it.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/dLFxw/1/. And the answer is yes, since [$add returns a Firebase ref](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/blob/master/angularfire.js#L125) it would show the path in toString().

Comment: Sorry for being a dolt, but where do I view console? I don't see any output

Comment: That depends on your browser: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Comment: Doh, I was thinking it was going to have a window in page, I realize 'which' console you're referring to then. I'll take a look, if mine still isnt working I'll post a more detailed example....

Comment: (Side note, I haven't been able to get to a PC yet, on my phone right now, I see you're adding a string, not an object, any chance you can update jsfiddle to match my example?)

Comment: Setting the value to an object/primitive is superfluous and won't have any affect on the outcome. Which brings me to another thought: if there were an undefined value in your object, that could be affecting the outcome (and would also display in the js console)

Comment: I have been printing the variables to log (for first/last/school), and they seem to be working correctly.

Comment: Hmmm, so apparently (no apparent changes) it's working now....well I'm sorry to be a pain. Not sure what happened.