# How can i return my firebase-data to $scope using resolve

Tags: angularjs, firebase

There is a service I use to get data from firebase:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('flbi.services.trainings', [])
    .factory('trainingsService', ['FBURL',
        function(FBURL) {
            return {
                getList: function() {

                    var queryLimit = 10;
                    var firebase = new Firebase(FBURL);

                    firebase.child('trainings').limit(queryLimit).on('value', function(trainings) {

                        var allTrainings = trainings.val();

                        $.each(allTrainings, function(training) {

                            firebase.child('users/' + allTrainings[training].userid).on('value', function(user) {

                                allTrainings[training].user = user.val();
                                allTrainings[training].user.gravatar = MD5(allTrainings[training].user.email);
                            });

                        });
                    });
                }
            };
        }]);
```

The function getList() is called from:

```
$routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'trainingsCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/default.html',
                resolve: {
                    "trainings": function(trainingsService) {
                        return trainingsService.getList();
                    }
                }
            })
```

And the controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('flbi.controllers.trainings', ['flbi.services.trainings'])
    .controller('trainingsCtrl', ['$scope', 'trainings',
        function($scope, trainings) {

            console.log(trainings); <-- just empty ....
            $scope.trainings = trainings;
        }]);
```

How can I return the data of allTrainings to my controller? I always get an empty Object. But if I check console.log(allTrainings) inner the on()-method of the service, it is full of data...

Comment: I tried to put a "return" everywhere in the getList()-method...

Comment: Anything that goes back to Firebase (or any web-based back end) ends up being an asynchronous call. When the code in `getList` is done executing, the data may not be back from Firebase yet. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463617/firebase-reference-not-returned-after-add-has-been-called/24467243#24467243. Is there any reason you're not using AngularFire? That solves large parts of the synchronization problem between Firebase and Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You resolve method must return a promise in order for this to work as expected. So your getList method should return a promise.

Also, prefer snapshot.forEach() to using .val() as this is highly optimized (it iterates the pointers rather than parsing and collecting all the data into an object and it also sorts the records to match the data, since JavaScript objects are inherently unordered).

```
angular.module('flbi.services.trainings', [])
.factory('trainingsService', ['FBURL', '$q',
  function(FBURL, $q) {
    return {
      getList: function() {
        var def = $q.defer();

        var queryLimit = 10;
        var firebase = new Firebase(FBURL);

        firebase.child('trainings').limit(queryLimit).on('value', function(trainings) {
          var promises = [];
          var allTrainings = {};
          trainings.forEach(function(ss) {
            var key = ss.name();
            var d = $q.defer();
            promises.push(d.promise);
            // put any other data you need in the trainings keys here
            // allTrainings[key].widget = ss.child('widget').val();
            firebase.child('users/' + allTrainings[key].userid).on('value', function(user) {

              allTrainings[key].user = user.val();
              var email = user.child('email').val();
              allTrainings[key].user.gravatar = MD5(email);
              d.resolve();
            }, d.reject);
            $q.when(promises).then(function() {
              def.resolve(allTrainings);
            }, def.reject);
          });
        }, def.reject);

      return def.promise;
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you, that worked! But there is a little blemish... I show the data with ng-repeat. If I get the first time on the page, there is a blank page. But if I go to an other Page (e.g. kontakt.html) and back to default.html, the data is shown...

Comment: You may need to add a $timeout inside of the $q.when().then(...) call to wrap def.resolve(). I thought that would happen when resolve() was called but maybe not.